# What is the most widely accepted theory on the ancient "Sea Peoples"?

Tags: ancient-history

There are many theories as to who they were.  The [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_Peoples) page has **nine** hypotheses.

What is the most widely accepted theory on who the ancient Sea Peoples were?

Comment: Sorry, but if you are linking to wikipedia in your question, which has information on them, what are you trying to get here in addition?  Theory is nice but it's pretty broad.

Comment: The question states quite clearly I want to know the most widely accepted theory

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with this question. Sure, it could be written a bit better, including info you already know for example, but it's fundamentally fair. Also, I believe the Anatolian and Minoan theories have a lot of support these days.

Comment: It's just linking to a wikipedia article and asking something off it without much detail here, that doesn't really add much to our site. I'd expect more detail here on the question.  Just to note I didn't downvote, I just asked about the question.

Comment: I think it's a valid question. Though Wikipedia lists allot of information, its Non-POV position means that it weights all possible theories evenly, even though some are less well supported than others. It's quite right to ask if any of the six theories is more likely than the others.

Comment: Wikipedia also has a habit of portraying fringe theories as equally valid, even when they have been dismissed by serious researchers.

Comment: I am happy to see others  than lennart are involved here he sees to be the only one to comment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The sea peoples are in Egyptian sources referred to as "foreign people of the sea". It is in other words a name they use for any sea-faring foreigners that attack Egypt. Some of the sources list the names of these sea peoples, making it clear that it is not one people that is meant.

The theories mentioned on Wikipedia may therefore all be correct at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The "sea peoples" that are mentioned by the Egyptians were probably, the Minoans....the ancient peoples of Crete. The Minoan Civilization lived and prospered during the Age of the Egyptian Pharaohs and Minoan Crete was also identified-(by the Greeks) as a "Thalassocracy"-(roughly translated as a "Sea Power" or "Rulers of the Sea"). Ancient Crete, (as well as present-day Crete), is located North of Egypt and trade (as well as diplomatic) relations between the 2 countries, was very likely. While there is no primary proof that the Minoans were the "sea peoples" referred to by the Egyptians, there is some interesting and intriguing circumstantial evidence.

The Egyptians may have also been referring to the Greco-Myceneans, who were also a seafaring peoples that settled into many Mediterranean territories once occupied by the Minoans-(including Crete proper). It is also plausible to suggest that the Greco-Mycenaeans may have had commercial and diplomatic relations with Pharaonic Egypt. The Myceneans, like the Minoan Cretans before them, also lived and prospered during the time of the Pharaohs. Again, while there is no primary proof supporting the Greco-Mycenean "sea people" thesis, a circumstantial case is not so implausible or unimaginable.

It is unlikely that the Egyptians were referring to the Carthaginians as "the sea peoples".  While the Carthaginians did establish their own impressive commercial empire throughout much of the Mediterranean region, their civilization followed the centuries old Pharaonic Age and had thrived during the 1st millennium BC/BCE, though not beforehand.

Comment: It would be appreciated if the downvoter would please explain why this answer received a downvote.  The answer is theoretically and circumstantially based, due to the fact that there is no substantial primary evidence of the existence of an ancient "sea peoples". 
However, based on the chronology, the close geographical proximity and the seafaring civilizations who lived and prospered in the Eastern Mediterranean during Pharaonic times, the Minoan or Mycenean thesis is not so implausible and a circumstantially based argument has some justification.

Comment: I would guess (it's not me, so I can't be sure) that the downvote is because you don't cite any sources. Which historians are saying that *"The "sea peoples" that are mentioned by the Egyptians were probably, the Minoans"*. On a more general point, if you backed up your answers by citing sources (by which I don't mean just saying 'relevant Wikipedia / Britannica' articles') and avoided just repeating what others have already said, you might not get so many downvotes on your answers.

Comment: Well, that's a good and noteworthy point, though I should mention that, due to personal matters, I don't necessarily have the abundance of time to meticulously cite or reference every posting. As someone who holds a Master's degree in History and as someone who has actually worked with primary sources, I am well aware of how the sourcing process works.  But, as I had mentioned to an earlier Commentator, this is an online public forum and not a graduate seminar.  An online public forum is, (at least the way I understand it), a less formalized and less rigidly structured setting when.....

Comment: compared with the rigors and expectations of a graduate setting.

Comment: [Why did my question get a downvote?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/618/why-did-my-question-get-a-downvote) applies to answers as well. Instead of whining about being downvoted, why not research the FAQ and Meta and learn this site's culture and expectations.

Comment: Asking a legitimate question about a downvote is not exactly "whining".

Comment: I am amazed that you claim to know the personal details of my day to day life.  When I said that I do not have "the abundance of time to meticulously cite or reference every posting", I was speaking from a comparative point of view and experience regarding my years as a graduate student and the rigorous expectations one had to fulfill and adhere to-(i.e. meticulous sourcing and citing).  It's been some time since I was in graduate school and the everyday demands of life do not always allow me-(and perhaps others), the luxury of time to source and cite every posting-(including, small postings).

Comment: I have already contacted the Support Dept. in order to remove my name and postings, though it looks like they have not done so.  Perhaps I will need to contact them once again.

Comment: My account has already been deleted.